# Creating Vuforia - Area Targets failed - E57 shall contain one or more Image2D structures

Tags: vuforia, point-clouds, e57, cloudcompare

so i am trying to create an Area Target with the "Vuforia Area Target Generator" for Unity3d.Therefore i need a e57-file containing the scanned PointCloud. Im getting this error:

```
E57 processing: Validation of the E57 file failed.
 [   FAIL  ] E57 shall contain one or more Image2D structures that have either 'sphericalRepresentation' field or 'pinholeRepresentation' field. 
 [ SUCCESS ] 'pose' field in Image2D structure shall be defined. 
 [ SUCCESS ] Spherical images shall have minimal resolution of 4096x2048 and their width = 2 * height. Pinhole images shall have minimal resolution of 1024x1024 and must be square (width = height).
```

I know that this means there are no images (panorama or 2d images) attached  !!and overlayed!!  to the e57-file. But i dont know how to add them to the e57-file. I tried using CloudCompare but after some research i found out that you cant registrate images to pointclouds in CloudCompare. Does anyone know a workaround or a solution(maybe a different software) to this problem? I do have a PointCloud as e57-file and a panorama as .png.

It took me quite a while to understand where the problem is because i thought a colorized Pointcloud would be enough to create an area target.

I should add that im not using one of the supported laserscanner that vuforia lists on their website. But it should work nonetheless as mention on theirs website as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Moritz

Comment: What brand of scanner are you using? Have you followed the instructions here? https://library.vuforia.com/area-targets/best-practices-scanning-environment Also note that for Leica scans there is a known problems with newer versions of the Cyclone software (see here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/20 )

Comment: So i am using a Trimble X7 which outputs an .e57 file and the corresponding panorama as .png. Vuforia mentioned this:
 "For all other 3D scanner types, the Area Target Generator (ATG) application can be used [...] The ATG processes files in the E57 format according to the ASTM E2807 standard ..."
The ASTM E2807 standard requires: "... 3D point data, attributes associated with 3D point data (color and intensity), and 2D imagery (digital photographs obtained using a 3D imaging system)... 
I do have everything required but i dont know how to append the panorama to the e57-file.

Comment: I should probably add that the problem is creating a usable e57-file following the ASTM E2807 standard. Working with vufoira AreaTargetGenerator is no problem for me. 
Maybe someone had the same issue and can recommend a software that can append/ attach/ overlay panoramic images to a pointcloud and export as .e57 file.
(Cloud Compare does not have these features)

Comment: CloudCompare can edit e57 files however it is going to be quite hard to create a valid e57 with containing correct information. For example one has to add the position (translation and rotation) of the images with respect to the scan coordinate system. The easiest way would be if the Trible software could embed the image in the E57 directly as that would ensure that this is done the right way.